The collapse is not displayed when the selected element is changed
earlier I asked how you can make a filter in swagger from the selection. here is the question itself:
changing the route list depending on the server port (swagger)
in the process of solving, I made sure that the filter worked:

but I accidentally found an error where if I collapse and select another element, it is not displayed:

Maybe I missed it somewhere, but I can't find it :


    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title>Swagger UI Example</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/swagger-ui/5.10.3/swagger-ui.css" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
      <style>
        body { background-color: #ffffff; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; }
      </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="swagger-ui"></div>
    <!-- Validator badge -->
    <img src="https://img.shields.io/badge/OpenAPI-Validator-green" alt="OpenAPI Validator Badge">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/swagger-ui/5.10.3/swagger-ui-bundle.js" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/swagger-ui/5.10.3/swagger-ui-standalone-preset.js" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
    <script>
      // Example JSON data
      const openApiJson = {
      "openapi": "3.1.0",
      "info": {
        "title": "blue_traktor_api",
        "description": "This API handles various functionalities for USEPI, Icons, Dashboard, Settings, Patterns, Devices, Widgets, and more.",
        "version": "0.1.0",
        "contact": {
          "name": "API Support",
          "url": "",
          "email": ""
        }
      },
      "servers": [
        {
          "url": "http://localhost:8000",
          "description": "TCP server for main operations"
        },
        {
          "url": "ws://localhost:8080",
          "description": "WebSocket server for updated parameters"
        }
      ],
      "paths": {
        "/api/usepi/patterns/create": {
          "post": {
            "tags": [
              "patterns"
            ],
            "summary": "http://localhost:8000",
            "operationId": "createPattern",
            "requestBody": {
              "required": true,
              "content": {
                "application/json": {
                  "schema": {
                    "$ref": "#/components/schemas/RequestStructure_PatternRequest"
                  },
                  "examples": {
                    "PatternExample": {
                      "summary": "An example of a PatternRequest",
                      "value": {
                        "data": {
                          "id": null,
                          "title": "test",
                          "description": "test desc",
                          "icon": "http://localhost:8000/api/icons/Cтатическое оборудование/Статическое оборудование.svg",
                          "createDate": null,
                          "updateDate": null,
                          "favourite": false,
                          "data": {
                            "ID": {},
                            "QR-Code": {},
                            "Position": {},
                            "DeviceParams": {}
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            },
            "responses": {
              "200": {
                "description": "Pattern created.",
                "content": {
                  "application/json": {
                    "schema": {
                      "$ref": "#/components/schemas/GoodResponse_Id"
                    }
                  }
                }
              },
              "500": {
                "description": "Internal Server Error",
                "content": {
                  "application/json": {
                    "schema": {
                      "$ref": "#/components/schemas/ErrorResponse"
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "/api/widgets/get": {
          "post": {
            "tags": [
              "widgets"
            ],
            "summary": "ws://localhost:8080",
            "operationId": "getWidget",
            "servers": [
              {
                "url": "ws://localhost:8080"
              }
            ],
            "requestBody": {
              "required": true,
              "content": {
                "application/json": {
                  "schema": {
                    "$ref": "#/components/schemas/RequestStructure_Id"
                  }
                }
              }
            },
            "responses": {
              "200": {
                "description": "Widget details.",
                "content": {
                  "application/json": {
                    "schema": {
                      "$ref": "#/components/schemas/GoodResponse_GetWidgetResponse"
                    }
                  }
                }
              },
              "500": {
                "description": "Internal Server Error",
                "content": {
                  "application/json": {
                    "schema": {
                      "$ref": "#/components/schemas/ErrorResponse"
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "components": {
          "schemas": {
            "PatternRequest": {
              "type": "object",
              "properties": {
                "id": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "nullable": true
                },
                "title": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "nullable": true
                },
                "description": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "nullable": true
                },
                "icon": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "nullable": true
                },
                "data": {
                  "type": "object",
                  "nullable": true
                },
                "favourite": {
                  "type": "boolean",
                  "nullable": true
                }
              }
            },
            "RequestStructure_PatternRequest": {
              "type": "object",
              "properties": {
                "data": {
                  "$ref": "#/components/schemas/PatternRequest"
                }
              }
            },
            "GoodResponse_Id": {
              "type": "object",
              "properties": {
                "statusCode": {
                  "type": "integer",
                  "format": "int32",
                  "enum": [
                    200
                  ]
                },
                "data": {
                  "$ref": "#/components/schemas/Id"
                }
              }
            },
            "Id": {
              "type": "object",
              "properties": {
                "id": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "nullable": true
                }
              }
            },
            "ErrorResponse": {
              "type": "object",
              "properties": {
                "statusCode": {
                  "type": "integer",
                  "format": "int32",
                  "enum": [
                    500
                  ]
                }
              }
            },
            "RequestStructure_Id": {
              "type": "object",
              "properties": {
                "data": {
                  "$ref": "#/components/schemas/Id"
                }
              }
            },
            "GoodResponse_GetWidgetResponse": {
              "type": "object",
              "properties": {
                "statusCode": {
                  "type": "integer",
                  "format": "int32",
                  "enum": [
                    200
                  ]
                },
                "data": {
                  "$ref": "#/components/schemas/GetWidgetResponse"
                }
              }
            },
            "GetWidgetResponse": {
              "type": "object",
              "properties": {
                "id": {
                  "type": "string"
                },
                "title": {
                  "type": "object"
                },
                "folderId": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "nullable": true
                },
                "icon": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "nullable": true
                },
                "data": {
                  "type": "object"
                },
                "type": {
                  "type": "string"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    };

      window.onload = function() {
        // Initialize Swagger UI with the JSON data
        const ui = SwaggerUIBundle({
          spec: openApiJson, // Using the JSON data
          dom_id: '#swagger-ui',
          deepLinking: true,
          presets: [
            SwaggerUIBundle.presets.apis,
            SwaggerUIStandalonePreset
          ],
          plugins: [
            SwaggerUIBundle.plugins.DownloadUrl
          ],
          layout: "StandaloneLayout"
        });
        window.ui = ui;

        // Function to filter elements based on selected value in dropdown
        function filterElements() {
          const selectElement = document.querySelector("#swagger-ui select");
          if (selectElement) {
            const selectedValue = selectElement.options[selectElement.selectedIndex].textContent.split(' - ')[0];
            const parentCatalogs = document.querySelectorAll("#swagger-ui .opblock-tag-section");

            parentCatalogs.forEach(parent => {
              let childVisible = false;
              const childElements = parent.querySelectorAll("[id^='operations-']:not([id^='operations-tag'])");
              childElements.forEach(childElement => {
                const summaryControl = childElement.querySelector(".opblock-summary-control > div > div");
                if (summaryControl) {
                  const summaryText = summaryControl.textContent.trim();
                  if (summaryText === selectedValue) {
                    childElement.style.display = ''; // Show element if it matches selected value
                    childVisible = true;
                  } else {
                    childElement.style.display = 'none'; // Hide element if it does not match
                  }
                }
              });

              // Hide parent element if no child elements are visible
              parent.style.display = childVisible ? '' : 'none';
            });
          }
        }

        // Event listener to detect changes in the dropdown and filter elements
        document.addEventListener('change', function(event) {
          const selectElement = document.querySelector("#swagger-ui select");
          if (event.target === selectElement) {
            filterElements();
          }
        });

        // MutationObserver to detect when the dropdown is added to the DOM and filter elements
        const observer = new MutationObserver(() => {
          const selectElement = document.querySelector("#swagger-ui select");
          if (selectElement) {
            filterElements();
            observer.disconnect(); // Stop observing once the dropdown is found and filtered
          }
        });

        // Start observing the DOM for changes
        observer.observe(document.querySelector('#swagger-ui'), { childList: true, subtree: true });
      };
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>




Can you please make a [mcve]

changed, Is it suitable?

If you click [edit] and then the [<>] snippet editor button, you can create a much smaller example where you mock the request with the object you posted

Thanks, I learned how to do it. Will it do?

Yes, but now the other code is not longer needed :)

I see the video, but I do not understand the problem. Can you give a step by step? I click on what and see what or do not see what?

1- you click on "server selection" at the top of the swagger ( http://localhost:8000 or ws://localhost:8080)
2- only those routes that have your choice marked in summary should be displayed. ( when choosing http://localhost:8000 it should seem like patterns with a suitable match for what is selected, in another case - widgets)
it's like a filter

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Sorry, I do not have time today. Perhaps someone else can help now there is something to test

It's okay, I'll keep you updated on the changes.

The problem was that when clicking on the parent element in the swager, the classes of the div blocks changed and it was necessary to click on the button to expand. and do it every time I change the selected item.
in the snippet, however, the first attempt to disclose the element for some reason does not work the first time, but if there is a full-fledged link instead of the url, then the rule will work without problems.
Thanks to everyone who participated, helped and was interested!


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Swagger UI</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/swagger-ui/5.10.3/swagger-ui.css" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="swagger-ui"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/swagger-ui/5.10.3/swagger-ui-bundle.js" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/swagger-ui/5.10.3/swagger-ui-standalone-preset.js" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script>
  window.onload = function() {

    // Define the Swagger specification directly in the JavaScript code
    const swaggerSpec = {
      "openapi": "3.1.0",
      "info": {
        "title": "blue_traktor_api",
        "description": "This API handles various functionalities for USEPI, Icons, Dashboard, Settings, Patterns, Devices, Widgets, and more.",
        "version": "0.1.0",
        "contact": {
          "name": "API Support",
          "url": "",
          "email": ""
        }
      },
      "servers": [
        {
          "url": "http://localhost:8000",
          "description": "TCP server for main operations"
        },
        {
          "url": "ws://localhost:8080",
          "description": "WebSocket server for updated parameters"
        }
      ],
      "paths": {
        "/api/usepi/patterns/create": {
          "post": {
            "tags": ["patterns"],
            "summary": "http://localhost:8000",
            "operationId": "createPattern",
            "requestBody": {
              "required": true,
              "content": {
                "application/json": {
                  "schema": {
                    "$ref": "#/components/schemas/RequestStructure_PatternRequest"
                  },
                  "examples": {
                    "PatternExample": {
                      "summary": "An example of a PatternRequest",
                      "value": {
                        "data": {
                          "id": null,
                          "title": "test",
                          "description": "test desc",
                          "icon": "http://localhost:8000/api/icons/Cтатическое оборудование/Статическое оборудование.svg",
                          "createDate": null,
                          "updateDate": null,
                          "favourite": false,
                          "data": {
                            "ID": {},
                            "QR-Code": {},
                            "Position": {},
                            "DeviceParams": {}
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            },
            "responses": {
              "200": {
                "description": "Pattern created.",
                "content": {
                  "application/json": {
                    "schema": {
                      "$ref": "#/components/schemas/GoodResponse_Id"
                    }
                  }
                }
              },
              "500": {
                "description": "Internal Server Error",
                "content": {
                  "application/json": {
                    "schema": {
                      "$ref": "#/components/schemas/ErrorResponse"
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "/api/widgets/get": {
          "post": {
            "tags": ["widgets"],
            "summary": "ws://localhost:8080",
            "operationId": "getWidget",
            "servers": [
              {
                "url": "ws://localhost:8080"
              }
            ],
            "requestBody": {
              "required": true,
              "content": {
                "application/json": {
                  "schema": {
                    "$ref": "#/components/schemas/RequestStructure_Id"
                  }
                }
              }
            },
            "responses": {
              "200": {
                "description": "Widget details.",
                "content": {
                  "application/json": {
                    "schema": {
                      "$ref": "#/components/schemas/GoodResponse_GetWidgetResponse"
                    }
                  }
                }
              },
              "500": {
                "description": "Internal Server Error",
                "content": {
                  "application/json": {
                    "schema": {
                      "$ref": "#/components/schemas/ErrorResponse"
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "components": {
        "schemas": {
          "PatternRequest": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
              "id": {
                "type": "string",
                "nullable": true
              },
              "title": {
                "type": "string",
                "nullable": true
              },
              "description": {
                "type": "string",
                "nullable": true
              },
              "icon": {
                "type": "string",
                "nullable": true
              },
              "data": {
                "type": "object",
                "nullable": true
              },
              "favourite": {
                "type": "boolean",
                "nullable": true
              }
            }
          },
          "RequestStructure_PatternRequest": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
              "data": {
                "$ref": "#/components/schemas/PatternRequest"
              }
            }
          },
          "GoodResponse_Id": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
              "statusCode": {
                "type": "integer",
                "format": "int32",
                "enum": [200]
              },
              "data": {
                "$ref": "#/components/schemas/Id"
              }
            }
          },
          "Id": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
              "id": {
                "type": "string",
                "nullable": true
              }
            }
          },
          "ErrorResponse": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
              "statusCode": {
                "type": "integer",
                "format": "int32",
                "enum": [500]
              }
            }
          },
          "RequestStructure_Id": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
              "data": {
                "$ref": "#/components/schemas/Id"
              }
            }
          },
          "GoodResponse_GetWidgetResponse": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
              "statusCode": {
                "type": "integer",
                "format": "int32",
                "enum": [200]
              },
              "data": {
                "$ref": "#/components/schemas/GetWidgetResponse"
              }
            }
          },
          "GetWidgetResponse": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
              "id": {
                "type": "string"
              },
              "title": {
                "type": "object"
              },
              "folderId": {
                "type": "string",
                "nullable": true
              },
              "icon": {
                "type": "string",
                "nullable": true
              },
              "data": {
                "type": "object"
              },
              "type": {
                "type": "string"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    };

    // Initialize Swagger UI with the provided specification
    const ui = SwaggerUIBundle({
      spec: swaggerSpec,
      dom_id: '#swagger-ui',
      deepLinking: true,
      presets: [
        SwaggerUIBundle.presets.apis,
        SwaggerUIStandalonePreset
      ],
      plugins: [
        SwaggerUIBundle.plugins.DownloadUrl
      ],
      layout: "StandaloneLayout"
    });

    window.ui = ui;

    let isFiltering = false;

    // Function to expand hidden elements
    function expandHiddenElements() {
      // Select all parent elements with the class 'opblock-tag-section'
      const parentElements = document.querySelectorAll('.opblock-tag-section');

      parentElements.forEach(parent => {
        // Find the header of the parent element
        const header = parent.querySelector('h3.opblock-tag');
        const isExpanded = header.getAttribute('data-is-open') === 'true';

        // If the element is hidden, expand it
        if (!isExpanded) {
          const expandButton = header.querySelector('button.expand-operation');
          if (expandButton) {
            expandButton.click();
            console.log(`Expanding parent element: ${header.textContent}`);
          } else {
            console.log(`Expand button not found for parent element: ${header.textContent}`);
          }
        }
      });
    }

    // Function to filter elements based on the selected value in the dropdown
    function filterElements() {
      const selectElement = document.querySelector('#swagger-ui>section>div.swagger-ui>div:nth-child(2)>div.scheme-container>section>div>div>div>label>select');
      if (selectElement) {
        // Get the selected value from the dropdown
        const selectedValue = selectElement.options[selectElement.selectedIndex].textContent.split(' - ')[0];
        console.log("Selected value from dropdown:", selectedValue);

        // Find all parent catalogs
        const parentCatalogs = document.querySelectorAll('#swagger-ui>section>div.swagger-ui>div:nth-child(2)>div:nth-child(4)>section>div>span> div > h3');
        console.log("Parent catalogs found:", parentCatalogs.length);

        parentCatalogs.forEach(parent => {
          // Find the parent element
          const parentElement = parent.closest('div.opblock-tag-section');
          if (parentElement) {
            let childVisible = false;
            // Find all child elements that are not tagged with 'operations-tag'
            const childElements = parentElement.querySelectorAll("[id^='operations-']:not([id^='operations-tag'])");
            childElements.forEach(childElement => {
              const summaryControl = childElement.querySelector('button.opblock-summary-control > div > div');
              if (summaryControl) {
                const summaryText = summaryControl.textContent.trim();
                // Display or hide child elements based on the selected value
                if (summaryText === selectedValue) {
                  childElement.style.display = '';
                  childVisible = true;
                  console.log(`---/Child Element ID: ${childElement.id} = ${summaryText}`);
                } else {
                  childElement.style.display = 'none';
                  console.log(`Hiding element with Child Element ID: ${childElement.id} as it does not match the selected value`);
                }
              } else {
                console.log(`Summary control not found for child element: ${childElement.id}`);
              }

              // Hide the description elements
              const elementsToRemove = childElement.querySelectorAll('.opblock-summary-description');
              elementsToRemove.forEach(element => {
                element.style.display = "none";
              });

              // Additional logic for elements with the class 'no-margin'
              if (childElement.querySelectorAll('.no-margin').length > 0) {
                const opblock = childElement;

                setTimeout(() => {
                  const elementToClear = opblock.querySelectorAll('.opblock-summary-path');
                  elementToClear.forEach(el => {
                    const dataPath = el.getAttribute('data-path').split('/').at(-1);
                    try { opblock.querySelectorAll('.opblock-description-wrapper')[0].style.display = "none"; } catch {}
                    if (dataPath !== 'list' && dataPath !== 'icons' && dataPath !== '{path}') {
                      opblock.querySelectorAll('.opblock-section-header')[0].style.display = "none";
                    }
                  });
                }, 30);
              }
            });

            // Hide or show parent elements based on the visibility of child elements
            if (isFiltering) {
              if (!childVisible) {
                parentElement.style.display = 'none';
                console.log(`Hiding parent element as all child elements are hidden: ${parent.textContent}`);
              } else {
                parentElement.style.display = '';
              }
            }
          } else {
            console.log("Parent element not found for:", parent.textContent);
          }
        });
      } else {
        console.log("Select element not found.");
      }
    }

    // Event listener for changes in the dropdown selection
    document.addEventListener('change', function(event) {
      const selectElement = document.querySelector('#swagger-ui > section > div.swagger-ui > div:nth-child(2) > div.scheme-container > section > div > div > div > label > select');
      if (event.target === selectElement) {
        isFiltering = true;
        expandHiddenElements(); // Expand hidden elements before filtering
        filterElements();
        isFiltering = false;
      }
    });

    // Event listener for clicks to trigger filtering
    document.addEventListener('click', () => {
      filterElements();
    });

    // MutationObserver to monitor changes in the DOM and apply filtering
    const observer = new MutationObserver(() => {
      const selectElement = document.querySelector('#swagger-ui > section > div.swagger-ui > div:nth-child(2) > div.scheme-container > section > div > div > div > label > select');
      if (selectElement) {
        isFiltering = true;
        expandHiddenElements(); // Expand hidden elements before filtering
        filterElements();
        isFiltering = false;
        observer.disconnect();
      }
    });

    observer.observe(document.querySelector('#swagger-ui'), { childList: true, subtree: true });

    // Apply filtering on the initial load
    isFiltering = true;
    expandHiddenElements();
    filterElements();
    isFiltering = false;
  };
</script>
</body>
</html>



